# shell save MySQL query result to a file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script which runs a MySQL query, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

user="root"
pwd="test"
database="mydb"
command="long... 
         long... query in
         multiple lines" 

mysql -u $user -p$pwd << EOF 
use $database;
$command
EOF
```

This query does a backup from a table to another. Is it possible to save the query result in a file without using mysql `INTO OUTFILE`? I only want to know if the query failed or succeeded.

If it succeeded something like `1 row(s) affected` or if it failed `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ...`

**Update**

Solution 1: () act as a chain of commands, so wrapping them in a variable gets the result of those commands. Then simply output the result of that variable in a file.

```
output=$( mysql -u $user -p$pwd << EOF 
use $database;
$command
EOF
)
echo "$output" >> /events/mysql.log
```

Solution 2: use tee as system command to send the result of the commands into a file, but this needs to be done from the crontab, like this:

```
*/1 * * * * root sh /events/mysql.sh |tee -a /events/mysql.log
```

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,391070,391983#msg-391983

**My working solution:**

```
user="root"
pwd="root12345"
database="mydb"
command="long ...long query"

mysql -u $user -p$pwd << EOF >> /events/mysql.log 2>&1
use $database;
$command;
EOF
```

Comment: use a regex to match if `affected` is present on the output.

Comment: Is that message not just the standard output from the `mysql` command? Does using `done > output.log` not work for this?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes it is a stantard output from mysql command. How to use done in this case?

Comment: Sorry, not `done` `EOF > output.log`. Just use normal shell output redirection to catch the `mysql` command's output. Use `> output.log 2>&1` to catch error output also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
output=$( mysql -u $user -p$pwd << EOF 
use $database;
$command
EOF
)
echo "$output" >> outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to handle error-messages is to through *stderr*. Use `2>&1` to catch the error.

So, add this to the end of your script:

`>> install.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like this:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    user="root"
    pwd="test"
    database="mydb"
    command="long... 
     long... query in
     multiple lines" 
    mysql -u$user -p$pwd -D$database -e "$command" > file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use the MySQL tee command to send output.

To get the logging process started, just use the tee command,

tee /tmp/my.out;

```
#!/bin/sh

user="root"
pwd="test"
database="mydb"
$pathToFile = "/tmp/my.out"
command="long... 
         long... query in
         multiple lines" 

mysql -u $user -p$pwd << EOF 
tee $pathToFile
use $database;
$command
EOF
```

**EDIT**
Since tee is reportedly not working inside script, you could also log output using Tee directly when running the script.

```
mysql_bash.sh > >(tee -a script.log)
```